Setting up a proxy for ssh access
I have a pac file that my university provides to access certain websites outside the university LAN. Usually for web-browsing I just add the pac file to firefox settings, and it connects without issue.
However, I wish to ssh to a machine which is also only available through the LAN. I tried setting up a system-wide proxy with https_proxy variable linking to the pac file url, but both wget and ssh load for a long time and do not connect successfully.
I searched a lot about this but only stumbled upon some very complex iptables manipulation, which I don't think is necessary to accomplish something simple.

The pac file tells web browsers to use a specific HTTP(S) or SOCKS proxy, presumably one controlled by the university. The proxy may have its own access control list, and/or may itself be restricted by a firewall. (Not doing at least one of those would be a rookie mistake from the university sysadmins, as it would leave the proxy open for all kinds of abuse.) So using the proxy specified in the pac file is most likely only going to give you the sort of limited access the university has intended, and nothing else.
